# Catalog of all significant earthquakes since 1900?

Tags: earthquakes

Where can I find a list of all earthquakes that happened on Earth since 1900?
I need time, longitude/latitude, and power -- preferably in .csv format.

Comment: Maybe at usgs. you have json data format. https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE. Where did you look for these data already on yourself? If you get the information here, you might try [OpenData.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Universal_learner thanks, I used exactly that website. The only problem I had was that I could get 20000 records at a time only. So I made a little script to get all the relevant data. I'll answer my own question how I did it.

Comment: You are welcome. That's what I said maybe. Haven't tried the api. xml also

Comment: I answered myself with a python script so someone else could use it in future... I hope I'm not breaking any rules answering myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so I got the data from
https://earthquake.usgs.gov

Since the website only allows to get 20k records at a time I made a little python script that downloads data for each month.

```
import os
import requests

for x in range(1900,2016):
    for y in range(1,13):
        url='https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query.csv?starttime='+str(x)+'-'+str(y)+'-31%2023:59:59&endtime='+str(x)+'-'+ str(y+1) +'-31%2023:59:59&minmagnitude=2.5&orderby=time'
        print(url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        with open(os.path.join("C:/Users/kristjag/OneDrive/delo/potresi", "potresi_"+str(x)+"_"+str(y)+".csv"), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

Code above take some time to finish but when completed you get earthquake data for every month from 1900-2016