# Where can I download historical sesimic data in CSV/Excel format for processing in R?

Tags: seismology, open-data

I'm not familiar with these kinds of data sets but I'm looking for some data for a project I'm working on. Essentially I would like multiple time series of seismic data from different stations over different periods. Is this sort of data freely available somewhere in a friendly CSV format?

Thanks for any help.

Luke

Answer (score 3):

You can download seismic data in csv format [at USGS](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php), from past hour, past day, past week and past month.

If you wish to download ancient data you need to use the [USGS API](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/). There is a query option: format=csv.

This is an example of an URL that gives you seismic data in csv format from 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-02:

https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=csv&starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02

[User Kristjan shared a Python script to ask the API for all available data since 1900](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14372/catalog-of-all-significant-earthquakes-since-1900/14373?r=SearchResults#14373).

Comment: In addition...they don't have time series, but a very useful seismic catalogue that may be of interest can be found at http://www.isc.ac.uk/iscbulletin/search/catalogue/. Search results can easily be saved as csv files.

Comment: I think the API has changed since Kristjan shared the script but you need to loop in a similar way to ask the API for long time series.